# Can Django be used for web services?

Tags: python, django, web-services, pylons

My friend said, "Pylons is so much better for web services."

My other friend said, "You can modify Django in a way to do exactly whatever you like."

In Django, what is necessary to be modified (urls.py? models classes? settings?) in order to do "web services" with APIs and REST and versioning, etc etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Django can be used for web services. Check out [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home):

> A mini-framework for Django for
>   creating RESTful APIs.
>
> Piston is a relatively small Django
>   application that lets you create
>   application programming interfaces
>   (API) for your sites.

Comment: That means django can not be used as a webservice 'out of the box'

Comment: Django can be used as a webservice 'out of the box' (see S.Lott's answer) but this app was created to make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we use it directly.  We have view functions that respond to some URI's with serialized JSON or XML objects instead of pretty HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

Django is in fact made to be used on server side. But first you need to understand that it is a framework.

A framework is a set of tools which get the common activities done in web development (e.g Login or Sign up module).